# How add horizontal separator in navdrawer?

Tags: android

I'm using navdrawer with support of `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`

I'd like to add a separator between groups (or first of "settings", it's not a problem), but I cannot find a method in web. Thank you for your support

base_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!--
        IF YOU NEED HEADER:
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/list_home" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/list_event"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_list_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/list_event" />

    </group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/settings" />

    </group>

</menu>
```

I did try to add View to drawer.xml but without success (simply nothing appear as divider):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/list_home" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/list_event"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_list_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/list_event" />

    </group>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="#000000"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/settings" />

    </group>




</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add different id's to your groups, like:

```
<group android:id="@+id/group1">

<group android:id="@+id/group2">
```

etc.

---

EDIT:
About height, I'm not sure if it work, but you can try add this to your `styles.xml` and apply this style to your `NavigationView` using `style="@style/MyNavigationView"` or `android:theme="@style/MyNavigationView"`:

```
<style name="MyNavigationView" parent="Widget.Design.NavigationView">
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It works. Like you can see, I set height of 10 dp (only to test); in my layout now I see them (I think) 1dp. Where I need to style them? Thank you ;-)

Comment: Check my edit; there is no parameter for divier, but this can work. Try it.

Answer (score -1):

You can add horizontal separator by this

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#3D7E9C"/>
```

If you want to add vertical separator , use android:layout_width="1dp"